# setDelegateQueue is not working on iOS5 but working fine on iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I am trying to perform a downloading in a background thread.For this, I have created an instance of NSOperationQueue and add an instance of NSInvocationOperation to it.

```
        operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
        // set maximum operations possible
        [operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];

        NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                selector:@selector(startBackgroundThread:)
                                                                                  object:data];

        [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
        [operation release];
```

Now in startBackgroundThread,I have created a new NSURLConnection and dispatching the operationQueue to it.

```
    currentConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
    if (self.operationQueue) {
        [currentConnection setDelegateQueue:self.operationQueue];
    }        
    [currentConnection start];
```

**Behavior in iOS6**

Working exactly fine on iOS6.
A thread gets created and NSURLConnection callbacks it delegates on the same background thread.

**Behavior in iOS5 and iOS5.1**

A thread gets created but NSURLConnection delegates didn't get called.

Am i missing something that need to be taken in account in iOS5?
I have read the documention provided by Apple but nothing is mentioned there related to that.

Comment: what are you tring to download? is it image for web page content?

Comment: If you start the connection on a thread whose runloop is running delegates will not be called.

Comment: So start the connection on main thread whose run loop will always be running

Comment: @pradeepa :I am downloading web content, and I have used a separate thread having its own runloop for creating the NSURLConnection. The problem is that the delegates are getting invoked in iOS6, but not in iOS5.0 and 5.1

Comment: okay you don't have to take burden of creating and managing threads, see the NSURLConnection api in my answer its easy to use. System will create the required number of threads on behalf of you and also it takes advantage of multicore processors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to perform a background web request then use the following convenience method.

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: queue: completionHandler:];
```

Block apis give better performance and recommended by apple.

Comment: Thanks....this solution is  working in iOS5 as well as iOS6.But still i am  in a dilemma as to why setDelegateQueue is not working on iOS5 whereas working fine on iOS6

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue on iOS 5. See http://openradar.appspot.com/10529053